# Use find_parent result to get specific items from it

Tags: python, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am seriously struggling to find out how to get it to work.

I am scraping few data from a website, but the content is put in a TABLE which has no classes.
As of that problem, I am running this to find out where the WORD I am searching for is:

```
item = soup.find_all(text=re.compile('WORD'))
```

And then, as the other content is in the same parent item, I do this:

```
parent = item.find_parent('tr')
```

Now, I am getting something like this:

```
<tr>
<td class="someclass1">WORD</td>
<td class="someclass2">TIRE</td>
<td class="someclass3">GUN</td>
<td class="someclass4">CAR</td>
<td class="someclass5">BYCICLE</td>
</tr>
```

As it did find the good place where the WORD is, how should I get the GUN or CAR out of it?
The main problem here is, as I said, there are multiple tables that have the same TD CLASSES, but only 1 of them has the WORD. The content that is in that table is the content I am looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With bs4 4.7.1 + you can use `:contains` and `:has` to isolate based on `WORD` being in element with a given class within a table. In the case you describe you could also work `:contains` direct off `table` i.e. `table = soup.select_one('table:contains("WORD")')` .

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html = '''
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <table> 
   <tbody>
    <tr> 
     <td class="someclass1">WORD</td> 
    </tr> 
   </tbody>
  </table>
  <table></table> 
  <table> 
   <tbody>
    <tr> 
     <td class="someclass1">NOT_WORD</td> 
    </tr> 
   </tbody>
  </table>
  <table></table>
 </body>
</html>
'''
soup = bs(html, 'lxml')
table = soup.select_one('table:has(.someclass1:contains("WORD"))')
print(table.text)
```

Comment: My reputation is still low so I cant vote your answer, but thank you mate... you are a life saver <3 Works like charm!